# A function that converges to $0$ at $a$ arbitrary fast is itself $0$ in a punctured neighbourhood of $a$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\mathbb{R}_{++}$ be the set of positive reals and let $f:\mathbb{R}_{++} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function. In what follows, $o$ is the little "o".

Assume that $f(g(x))=o(x)$ for any $g:\mathbb{R}_{++} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{++}$ such that $g(x)=o(1)$ as $x\to0+$. I am trying to prove that then there is $\epsilon>0$ such that $f$ is zero on $(0,\epsilon)$.

My attempt.

1. Assuming, contrary to the claim, that $f$ is non-zero on some interval $(0,\epsilon)$, I am trying to construct a continuous and strictly increasing function $h:\mathbb{R}_{++} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{++}$ such that $h(x)=o(f(x))$.
2. Then for any $g:\mathbb{R}_{++} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{++}$ such that $g(x)=o(1)$ we must have $h(g(x))=o(f(g(x)))=o(o(x))=o(x)$. Setting $g=h^{-1}$, we arrive to a contradiction: $x=o(x)$.

But I am stuck with construction of a function $h$ at step 1. Any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: You mean assuming the negation, not the converse.

Comment: Thank you very much. Fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume otherwise. Then there exists a sequence $x_n$ strictly decreasing to $0$ with $y_n:=f(x_n)\ne 0$. Using the property with $g(x)=x$, we see that $|y_n|<x_n$ for $n\gg0$. By picking a subsequence if necessary, $|y_n|$ can be assumed to be strictly decreasing.
Define $h$ such that $h(|y_n|)=x_n$ (and interpolate). Then $h$ is $o(1)$, but $f(h(|y_n|))=y_n$ shows that $f\circ h$ is not $o(x)$.

If we make $h(|y_n|^2)=x_n$, then $f\circ h$ is not even $O(x)$.

Comment: Thank you very much!